# Is it possible to delete files on android from a usb PC connection?

Tags: usb, file-transfer, file-management, mtp

From PC (Linux) connected on an Android device through an USB connection, is it possible to delete files on the Android device ?

*(Running Android >9 on smartphone, PC OS: Linux)*

The standard connection I get is through MTP (USB mass storage connection does not seem available).

Comment: yes it's possible via MTP or adb

Comment: As you know about MTP and ADB I am not sure what answer you expect.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.